# Vue, component tag, dynamic component injection

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

In the code below, if `retrieveComponent('test')` return undefined, what append for the  tag (about perfomance) ? Use a v-if condition could be a better solution ?

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import {defineAsyncComponent} from "vue/dist/vue";

function retrieveComponent(componentName){
  let module = undefined;
  try {
    module = defineAsyncComponent(() => import((`../components/modules/${componentName}/${componentName}Component.vue`)));
  }catch (e){ }
  return module;
}
</script>

<template>
  <component :is="retrieveComponent('test')" style="display: block"/>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add an errorComponent in this case, see
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html#loading-and-error-states.

```js
const AsyncComp = defineAsyncComponent({
  // the loader function
  loader: () => import('./Foo.vue'),

  // A component to use while the async component is loading
  loadingComponent: LoadingComponent,
  // Delay before showing the loading component. Default: 200ms.
  delay: 200,

  // A component to use if the load fails
  errorComponent: ErrorComponent,
  // The error component will be displayed if a timeout is
  // provided and exceeded. Default: Infinity.
  timeout: 3000
})
```

Also importing from "vue/dist/vue" looks wrong?

Comment: Thank for this, but i want to know if add ``v-if`` condition is better or not about performance (versus using the errorComponent of defineAsyncComponent for exemple).

Comment: well you could have formulated your question a bit better :D but this sounds like premature optimization to me, and it all depends on what you actually want to achieve

Comment: Insted of returing an undefined module i chose to load a default module for error case. In fact your solution is better because it fix the problem from the start and also allows it to be managed more easily and without raising an exception. Thanks !